# Context menu on Treeview does not open on selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview with a context menu and I am using an converter to manage it. I do not want the menu to open on items and just want it to open on nodes.

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
  <ContextMenu x:Key="AddNew" Name="PopMnu" Visibility="{Binding IsFolder,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
    <MenuItem Header="New Symbol..." Click="AddSymbolMenu_Click"/>
    <MenuItem Header="New Folder..." Click="NewFolderItem_Click"/>
  </ContextMenu> 

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource AddNew}"/>
  </Style>
```

When I right click on an item, no menu comes up but now when I right click on a node, the menu comes up but on the location of the item previously right clicked. Also the menu does not dismiss unless you right click again on any item. Any help please?

Comment: Back to the previous question, do you have separate viewmodels for the type folder and item? I am guessing a folder can contain a folder or an item and an item cannot contain anything below it. So if you create a DataTemplate for a folder and another one for the item and attach the context menu only to the folder template, then it will be much more cleaner code and might solve your problem as well. Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: @Krishna Your comment should be an answer really - possibly with a code sample? :-)

Comment: I have one VM. There is a ISFolder property to find if an item is a folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Krishna's comment suggested, a solution would be to have a view model for a folder and one for an item

```
public class Folder : ViewModelBase { }   
public class Item : ViewModelBase { }
```

Then you can define a DataTemplate for each, one containing a context menu the other without.

```
 <TreeView Name="SymbolsTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <Grid Background="Red">
                        <Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" >
                <Grid >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I have one VM but two ObservableCollection where one is ParentObservableCollection each parent has list of children ChildObservableCollection. The problem does not occur if I have menu on each item as well. I had to implement "Remove" as well so with two menus the problem is not seen but I did not have to change my code at this stage.